# Как открыть файл, у которого пробелы в пути?

Tags: c++, windows, консоль

Заменяла `\` на `\\` все равно не открывается.

Пример пути `C:\Users\Jessy\Desktop\ключи проект.txt`

```
string path;
getline(cin, path);

fstream file;
file.open(path, fstream::in);

if (!file.is_open()) {
    cout << "Помилка відкриття файлу" << endl;
}
```

[image: скриншот запуска]

Comment: Заменить \ на \\ - если это литерал C/C++, и взять в кавычки `\"` (но это нужно не везде и не всегда, надо смотреть, что и как вы делаете)...

Comment: @Harry https://img.serpstat.com/jessy/PMFnIqnMIe.png

Comment: Это не исходник, что от этой картинки толку?...

Comment: @Harry код в посте

Comment: Не надо вводить кавычки - здесь имя файла - просто имя файла :) Кавычки - это, например, в командной строке для объединения кусков в один аргумент. Все хорошо в меру, там, где оно нужно. Здесь кавычки *не* нужны.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как есть, так и открыть. Никаких кавычек, двойных слешей и экранирований не надо.

Comment: ну если бы так открывалось, я бы не спрашивала

Comment: Я на твойм скрине вижу, что ты вводишь в кавычках.

Comment: ок, кавычки удалила и все заработало. Но это какой-то бред, почему работает с кавычками, когда в пути нет пробелов?

Comment: Не знаю, по идее в обоих не должно.

Comment: спасибо большое